# Description for Android app

Tags: android

I create an app, and I know how to put describe for my app. But I don't know how to put description for my app. Help me please!

Comment: Please rephrase your question. What description? The Android Market description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i could not get you what exactly you want but as much as i can understand i am providing following solution link for help.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html